# Open .ipa with Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipa

We bought 2300€ the application development 6 months ago, the developer has provided us with the Xcode project but the problem is that my Mac has been stolen ... The developer has disappeared ...

**Is it possible to generate a one Xcodeproj by unzipping ipa?**

*Mac Os X 10.8.2 - Xcode 4.5.2*

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry you're in this position, but it's not on topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. ipa includes compiled and encrypted executable. You should better search for developer, and become a person who 'already making backups'.

Comment: OK, thank you. I had backups but my house is robbed so I have nothing at all! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are offline backup services.